# Using Integrating factor to solve an equation

Tags: calculus

How can I use integrating factor to solve y' = 2x + y.

Please provide the steps with explanation. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know about integrating factor, but this is pretty simple with variation of parameters.

Comment: $y^\prime - y = 2x$ is a linear first order differential equation. A suitable integrating factor would then be $e^{\int -1 \,\mathbb d x} = e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$y' = 2x + y$$ Move the "$y$'s" to one side to get $$y' - y = 2x$$ Remember, we want to make this left side look like a product rule.  In other words, we want it to look something like $$y'f(x) + f'(x)y$$ In general, we want $f(x)$ to be of the form $f(x) = e^{rx}$ for some constant $r$. So let's try that out: $$y'(e^{rx}) + re^{rx}y$$

Just by guessing, it looks like $r = -1$ is a good candidate, because then we get $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $f'(x) = -e^{-x}$. I "guessed this" by noting that we want the $y'$ term and the $y$ term to be multiplied by the same function, but the $y$ term should be negative. So let's multiply that out into our original equation to get $$e^{-x}y' - e^{-x}y = 2x e^{-x}$$ Now this is the product rule, namely $$e^{-x}y' - e^{-x}y = (ye^{-x})'$$ So we make the substitution. $$(ye^{-x})' = 2x e^{-x}$$ Now we integrate both sides: $$ye^{-x} = \int 2x e^{-x} dx$$ Now I trust you can use integration by parts to find the antiderivative of the right side, and then you solve for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

So you have (looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Use_in_solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations))

$$
M(x)\left(y' - y\right) = M(x)2x
$$

So we need to find a function $f(x, y)$ such that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x, y) = M(x)y' + M(x)y$.  It's clear that f(x, y) should be $f(x, y) = g(x)y$ such that:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x, y) = g'(x)y + g(x)y' = M(x)y' - M(x)y
$$

This means:

$$ 
g(x) = -M(x)\\
g'(x) = M(x)
$$

Which is $g'(x) = -g(x)$ which is clearly $g(x) = Ae^{-x}$.  Which makes $M(x) = -Ae^{-x}$.  This gives:

$$
-Ae^{-x}\left(y' - y\right) = Ae^{-x}y - Ae^{-x}y' = \left.\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right(-Ae^{-x}y\right)
$$

Now we have...dropping the $A$ which we don't need (it will cancel in the final equation):

$$
\left.\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right(-e^{-x}y\right) = -2e^{-x}x
$$

We can now integrate to get:

$$
-e^{-x}y = -2\int xe^{-x}dx
$$

$$
\int xe^{-x}dx = -xe^{-x} + \int e^{-x}dx = -xe^{-x} - e^{-x} + C
$$

Finally giving:

$$
-e^{-x}y = 2xe^{-x} + 2e^{-x} + C \\
y = -2x -2 + Ce^{x}
$$

We can verify this is correct:

$$
y' = -2 + Ce^{x} \\
y' - y = -2 + Ce^{x} + 2x + 2 - Ce^{x} = 2x
$$

Comment: And I should say, we could have also dropped the negative as it is part of $A$, so we could have proceeded with $\left.\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right(e^{-x}y\right) = 2xe^{-x}$